# Any way to see .class files in Package Explorer in Eclipse

Tags: java

I'm new on java, actually when i create a project in eclipse there are only java files ,i want to see .class files also in Package Explorer  any way to do this.Actually i wana do JAR operations.

Comment: They exist just fine, but there'd be no point in showing them. It's just pointless noise. Presumably you think you need to see them for some unstated (and likely incorrect) assumption. Perhaps update the question? Nobody wakes up and goes: I know! I want to see class files in my package explorer! You're trying to accomplish something else. There's probably a better way than 'somehow make class files appear'. Unless you speak of class files from dependencies, those _are_ already in your package explorer, by default. If you don't see them you didn't add them to the project yet.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: i just updated, Actually .class files are not visible in my Package Explorer